# Pandas groupby: different indexes returned

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

```
Versions:
* Pandas 0.21.0
* Python 2.7.12
```

I see this strange behaviour in Pandas: according to the dataframe and the sort, groupby returns different results:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dtime': [datetime(2017,1,1,1,5), datetime(2017,1,1,1,20)],
                   'val1': [11, None],
                   'val2': [None, 31]
                  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dtime': [datetime(2017,1,1,1,5), datetime(2017,1,1,1,20)],
                   'val1': [11, None],
                   'val2': [31, None]
                  })



df1b = df1.melt("dtime").dropna().set_index("dtime")
df2b = df2.melt("dtime").dropna().set_index("dtime")

r1a = df1b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True))
r1b = df1b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))

r2a = df2b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True))
r2b = df2b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))

print "\n--- df1 ascending sort ---------------\n", r1a
print "\n--- df1 descending sort SHOULD IT ALWAYS BE LIKE THIS? --------------\n", r1b
print "\n--- df2 ascending sort ---------------\n", r2a
print "\n--- df2 descending sort --------------\n", r2b
```

return

```
--- df1 ascending sort ---------------
dtime
2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
2017-01-01 01:20:00    31.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df1 descending sort SHOULD IT ALWAYS BE LIKE THIS? --------------
dtime                dtime              
2017-01-01 01:00:00  2017-01-01 01:20:00    31.0
                     2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df2 ascending sort ---------------
dtime
2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
2017-01-01 01:05:00    31.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df2 descending sort --------------
dtime
2017-01-01 01:05:00    31.0
2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Why  `df1 descending sort` returns the reference time for grouping (`2017-01-01 01:00:00`), while it is missing in the other groups? 
I would expect that all grouping return a reference time as multi-index, without exception.

I created an issue at [github pandas #18908](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18908) but in a month had no useful answer. I would like to understand if it is just a presentation problem or a possible bug.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Which versions of Pandas and Python are you using, in case that makes a difference when verifying?

Comment: Of course, that could be important: Python 2.7.12 and Pandas 0.21.0

Comment: Thats really strange more probably a bug

Comment: Do I assume correctly that we should always read a multi index (grouping reference time + dtime), like in `df1 descending`? 

It is very strange to me not to read it in the result, as it is the main reason why I am grouping data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tested on Python 3.5 and Pandas 0.22 - using slightly different code (`pd.melt()` instead of `df.melt`).*

**Firstly - the reason for the difference.**

`df1` has values for two different timestamps (01:20:00 and 01:05:00), where df2 both observations that remain are on the same timestamp (01:05:00).

I'm not exactly sure why, but evidently the act of reversing the sort means does mean that the `.values` call is including the grouper time window on `df1` because you're sorting values as descending within a ascending timeindex. The result is different for `df2` because the timestamps are identical and so the grouper isn't required. You possibly already deduced that, so apologies for duplication if so.

**Suggestion to consistently show your expected result**

Normally when working with `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` I would use an aggregation call to manipulate the data (`max` in the example below but `sum`, `count` and others are available). If you're looking to see your values with the reference time of the grouper, this would be the way to approach it:

Here's df1b, with multiple timestamps against the observation values:

```
In []: df1b.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="1h"), df1b.index, "variable"])\
       .max().sort_values("value", ascending=False)
Out[]:
                                                  value
dtime               dtime               variable
2017-01-01 01:00:00 2017-01-01 01:20:00 val2       31.0
                    2017-01-01 01:05:00 val1       11.0
```

...and same approach for df2b:

```
In []: df2b.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="1h"), df2b.index, "variable"])\
       .max().sort_values("value", ascending=False)
Out[]:
                                                  value
dtime               dtime               variable
2017-01-01 01:00:00 2017-01-01 01:05:00 val2       31.0
                                        val1       11.0
```

Does this help? Or have I missed the significance of why you were working with the `.values` method?

*Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with working with `groupby.value` so you might be trying to achieve something I've missed.*

Comment: Thank you , @Phil! The hint to show consistently the same result works perfectly. To tell the truth I need yet to understand why it works, but I will take some time to see what's happening. I don't need the "insertion time" but just the "group time", so I will remove the former from the multi index. Is it, according to you, a possible bug not to show the group time after a groupby or an acceptable result?

Comment: Alex see my examples below; I think/hope they clarify why this is happening.  That said, @Phil's fix is the way to go.

Comment: @AlexPoca I personally don't think this is a bug, because your original method is bypassing the conventional way of using `.groupby` and accessing the values directly. But I'm just a user and not involved in the project, so it's just an opinion. I've learned something new, as I've never had reason to access the results so I've gained a little something here too :)

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is at first unexpected, but I do not think it is a bug. 
 First, note that it is **not** `ascending=False` that causes this behavior (see examples below).  Second, when the grouper is called such that the multi-index reference time would be redundant (or unnecessary), it is skipped.  And this occurs when the values being sorted are in *the same order* as the timestamps.  I see @Phil Sheard has proposed an approach to get your expected result (+1 for that), so below I am just expanding on the behavior and why I think it is sensible for `pd` to be doing that.

First, notice that this behavior happens equivalently on the ascending search when I make a `df3` that has the `val` data in the opposite order:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dtime': [datetime(2017,1,1,1,5), datetime(2017,1,1,1,20)],
                   'val1': [11, None],
                   'val2': [None, 31]
                  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dtime': [datetime(2017,1,1,1,5), datetime(2017,1,1,1,20)],
                   'val1': [11, None],
                   'val2': [31, None]
                  })

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'dtime': [datetime(2017,1,1,1,5), datetime(2017,1,1,1,20)],
                   'val1': [None, 11],
                   'val2': [31, None]
                  })


df1b = df1.melt("dtime").dropna().set_index("dtime")
df2b = df2.melt("dtime").dropna().set_index("dtime")
df3b = df3.melt("dtime").dropna().set_index("dtime")

r1a = df1b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True))
r1b = df1b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))

r2a = df2b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True))
r2b = df2b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))

r3a = df3b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True))
r3b = df3b.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1h")).value.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))


print("\n--- df1 ascending sort ---------------\n {}".format(r1a))
print("\n--- df1 descending sort SHOULD IT ALWAYS BE LIKE THIS? --------------\n {}".format(r1b))
print("\n--- df2 ascending sort ---------------\n {}".format(r2a))
print("\n--- df2 descending sort --------------\n {}".format(r2b))
print("\n--- df3 ascending sort SHOULD IT ALWAYS BE LIKE THIS? --------------\n {}".format(r3a))
print("\n--- df3 descending sort --------------\n {}".format(r3b))
```

which returns:

```
--- df1 ascending sort ---------------
 dtime
2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
2017-01-01 01:20:00    31.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df1 descending sort SHOULD IT ALWAYS BE LIKE THIS? --------------
 dtime                dtime              
2017-01-01 01:00:00  2017-01-01 01:20:00    31.0
                     2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df2 ascending sort ---------------
 dtime
2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
2017-01-01 01:05:00    31.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df2 descending sort --------------
 dtime
2017-01-01 01:05:00    31.0
2017-01-01 01:05:00    11.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df3 ascending sort SHOULD IT ALWAYS BE LIKE THIS? --------------
 dtime                dtime              
2017-01-01 01:00:00  2017-01-01 01:20:00    11.0
                     2017-01-01 01:05:00    31.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

--- df3 descending sort --------------
 dtime
2017-01-01 01:05:00    31.0
2017-01-01 01:20:00    11.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

**Notice** that the multi-index reference is there when the sorted values induce the time stamps to be out of order, but absent (as unnecessary) otherwise. I have done this with more than two values (and other permutations) and the behavior is the same.

**Final Comment** As stated, I don't think it's a bug.  That said, I agree with you that it's not necessarily the most natural design choice, as it leads to strange differences like the one you've found.

Comment: Thank you, @muskrat. Interesting observations indeed.